# Introducing your pro-tem moderators

Tags: discussion, moderators

Throughout the beta, we need members from the site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderators Pro Tempore**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

I am pleased to announce, at long last, that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us assure that each community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Andy]
[image: ArtOfCode]
[image: Cfinley]

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

**Almost certainly**. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My failure to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why we eventually hold elections.

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

P.S. Sorry Undo, I know you were craving a "you're doing it all wrong" post from me. But this is better, yeah?

Comment: Awww, no "you're doing it all wrong" post? It's just not right not having to see that title every time I try to find something on meta.

Comment: `P.S. Sorry Undo, I know you were craving a "you're doing it all wrong" post from me. But this is better, yeah?` Dont worry there's still time to undo this grave decision!

Comment: FLEE YOU FOOLS. I mean congratulations.

Comment: SPEECH! SPEECH! SPEECH!

Comment: Finally! Congratulations!

Answer (score 6):

Blame Andy. Andy demanded a speech. And 3 other people agreed with him.

---

I'd like to thank my family, my friends, my peers, the Queen, Lord Shog, animuson, and Tony the Pony. (Geek pride in getting that reference.) Oh, and whoever it was that pressed the promote button. I'll find that out later. (later: it was Shog, so that's already done)

But seriously, I'm sure I speak for all the new mods here when I say thanks for your votes of confidence, and I hope we do you proud. Come talk to us anytime, about anything - we're all pretty conspicuous in chat. I look forward to working with you all.