# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #2](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2) on Hardware Recommendations has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: JMY1000]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/election/2) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5678118118359040).

Let's also take the time to thank the departing mod ArtOfCode, who'd been a part of [the original batch of pro-tem mods appointed back in 2015](https://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/313/112), for their service to this community throughout the years.

Comment: Thanks for your votes! Looking forward to serving on the moderator team for Hardware Recommendations :)

Answer (score 1):

May I be the first to offer JMY1000 congratulations on being our community's newly elected moderator!

I'm confident they will do a great job, and I want to personally thank them for helping our community.

Also many thanks to retiring moderator ArtOfCode for all their help over the years!

Answer (score 0):

I might be a bit late but congrats my man! Please tell me about the experience so far, do you enjoy it? Is it tough? Do you have to spend a lot of time in front of the screen?